Is there a proper analysis of how profitable Technical Analysis is?
I often get spammed with tips about hammers, fibonacci sequences, ceilings etc.
Usually they come with a single example of where it worked great.
Given how many people keep focus on this I suspect there is more to this than just a cherry picked example, but I wondered if there is any indication of how much more.
Key factors that would ideally all be considered at once (though finding something on even one is already hard):

Historical performance over several years, sliced by various market conditions
Moving beyond likelihood (it is great if something works 80% of the time but perhaps the losses are 5x bigger than the gains in bad scenarios)
Costs of trading, thinking about cost of transactions mostly but perhaps alsoncapital. (No need to account for costs of applying the methodology or time used.) Stretch: Tax, spending or other annual effects
4.Impact of portfolio mgmt constraints (let's assume we have 10k, or even 100k usd but are not able or willing to put in millions), if you lose the farm once you are done so probably everything you analyze has 20x less impact (and somewhat higher costs) than it could as you spread the risk. Another constraint may be that markets close overnight.

And of course this leaves the usual challenges such as observation bias.
Hence the question:
Is there any quantitive historical analysis that somehow can translate to real world impact?

What have I found:

It is suggested advanced models can perform quite well. Presumably there are practical constraints such as speed or change to make these less practically accessible in daily life. (Not looking for recommendations to subscribe to your solution for a small fee...)
A broad search on actual impact mostly results in claims regarding the likelihood of individual decisions being right, occasionally something more relevant like 'we achieve a few % extra profit', but always these statements are unnacked and unqualified (few % of what, annual RoE?)
I have seen some successful traders buy nice cars, but not airplanes, so even if it goes well it seems an exponential return on capital is not very common.


"I often get spammed with tips about hammers, fibonacci sequences..." Just ignore that stuff, don't waste any time on it.

This question is similar to: Theoretical justification for technical analysis. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@alper The question is actually much more narrow but the top voted answer is actually so extensive that it gives a pretty decent idea of what the answer to my question would be. Thanks!
